# Python: global variables coming into a function even though they're not passed in

Tags: python

I've just discovered this weird thing where if I create a global variable called for example `numbers` and then call a function with a default variable with the same name it accesses that global variable even though it's not specifically passed in or referenced with the `global` operator. This seems like it shouldn't be possible. Is there a reason why this happens and is this explained anywhere in the Python documentation?

This example shows what I mean:

```
def append(number, numbers=[]):
    print(numbers)
    numbers.append(number)
    return numbers

numbers = append(1)
different_numbers = append(2)

print(numbers, 'end')
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2] end
```

Comment: See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: `numbers` isn't a global; your function has a parameter named `numbers` that exists whether or not you pass an argument. If you *don't* pass an argument, it uses a separate, function-specific list as its value, not the list bound to the global name `numbers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists store references ("pointers") to the objects.

You changing the actual list when you do that.

First your function creates a `numbers` variable that, prints an empty list, then returns a list to the `numbers` in your statement `numbers = append(1)`

Now there exists a numbers variable with a 1 in it, which is pointing to the numbers that was created by your function.

when you `append(2)`, you first print what was already in the numbers variable that exists from your function, then you append 2 to it.

Finally you print the numbers that already exists.

You are in effect pointing to the same array in all 2 or 3 variables.

You can try using hex(id(x)) to find the location of the variable.

Try this

```
def append(number, numbers=[]):
    print(numbers)
    print(hex(id(numbers)))
    numbers.append(number)
    print(hex(id(numbers)))
    return numbers

numbers = append(1)
print (hex(id(numbers)))
different_numbers = append(2)

print(numbers, 'end')
print (hex(id(numbers)))
print (hex(id(different_numbers)))
```

You should get the same address for each line every time, but if you `del numbers` and `del different_numbers` after each run, you will change the address the array is stored at but it will be the same within each run.

Comment: if you run the code more than once make sure you ```del numbers``` and ```del different_numbers```

Answer (score 0):

If a variable with the same name is defined inside the scope of function as well then it will print the value given inside the function only and not the global value.